# How to get all contents of specific directory from remote branch in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

I wanted to merge changes of remote branch say `release` into my local branch say `test-automation`. In  order to do that, I checkout to `test-automation` and hit following command -

```
git pull upstream release
```

This command was successful but when I checked contents of some files from remote `release` branch with my local code on branch `test-automation`, I could see some of remote changes were not in my local branch. After several attempts, I could not achieve it.

I'm not sure what other files also have discrepancy. But in my local branch, I've change in only `pom.xml`. Is there any way in git, I can take entire code from remote branch for specific directory (say `src` directory of maven structure in my case)?

Comment: Can you get the contents of a specified directory now?

Answer (score 0):

#### What the problem was?

When you write: `git pull upstream release` then it's assumed by git that you are getting the "upstream" branch and are trying to merge it with your release branch on your local repository.

#### Solution to fix the problem:

Try this instead:

`git fetch origin`

`git checkout test-automation`

`git merge origin/release`

(I've assumed that your remote repository is called origin)

You should have merged the changes into your test-automation branch - perhaps fix any conflicts if any exist.